# How to write unit test for method which use third party library

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a simple method which uses Unirest library to send http requests. I need to write unit test for it:

```
public HttpResponse<JsonNode> sendRequest(Map params) throws UnirestException {
        return Unirest.get(apiUrl).queryString("key", apiKey).queryString(params).asJson();
    }
```

I assume that I need to mock it somehow but I have no idea how.

Comment: Given there's a static method on here, you may need something like Powermock.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve by testing this method? Is it code coverage? Why do you bother unit testing a delegate method?

Comment: @luc14n0 All methods in my application are like this, and I need to write unit tests for them

Comment: @biomaks may be you need a fake rest server and don't to mock `Unirest`. and write a little integration test to test `Unirest`.